# php: Calculate Date from Week of Year and Day of Week

Tags: php, date, time

I am currently struggling with the following: I need to get the Date like `"Sun, 29.05.2016 18:00"` but all i have is the number of the week from the beginning of the year, the number of the day of week and the hour of the day.

```
Week: 21
Day:  7
Hour: 18
```

Now my question is how do i get the actual date and time with php's date functions or own code?

Comment: you can try with `setISODate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [DateTime::setISODate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
$week_no = 21;
$day =7;
$hour = 18;

$d= new DateTime();
$d->setISODate(date('Y'),$week_no, $day);
$d->setTime ($hour,0);
echo $d->format('D, d.m.Y H:i');
```

Comment: This worked just fine. Thank you very much. I didn't know there was something like "setISODate". You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward with DateTime objects:

```
$week = 21;
$day = 7;
$hour = 18;

$dateFormat = sprintf('%d-W%02d-%d', (new DateTime())->format('Y'), $week, $day);

$x = new DateTime($dateFormat);
$x->setTime($hour, 0);
echo $x->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

(assuming the current year)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `setISODate` and `DateTime`. [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/QhWaE)

Setting the 2016 from your desire output and use the hour directly to the format.

```
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2016, 21, 7); //year , week num , day
echo $gendate->format('D, d.m.Y 18:00'); //Sun, 29.05.2016 18:00
```